# Why the form disappear using ngFor directive

Tags: html, angular6, ngfor

When I am using `ngFor` directive in the form tag, the entire form will  disappear. Can anyone guide me on how I can fix this issue?

```
<form #myforms="ngForm" *ngFor="let i of editaddress">

<div class="p-3 p-lg-5 border">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="c_fname" class="text-black">Save this address as<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control c_fname" value="{{i.title}}" name="title" [(ngModel)]="location.title" #title=ngModel>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="c_fname" class="text-black">First Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control c_fname" value="{{i.first_name}}" name="fname" [(ngModel)]="location.first_name" #fname=ngModel>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="c_lname" class="text-black">Last Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control c_lname" value="{{i.last_name}}" name="lname" [(ngModel)]="location.last_name" #lname=ngModel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Save" (click)="saveAddress(location)">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it mean editaddress is an empty array and if it shows and disappears, at some point the controller sets the variable to an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not show any part of the underlying controller, the only thing I can do is inform you that the property *editaddress* would be an empty array.  Therefore it would not render anything.

If it flashes and disappears, it means that through your life cycle the array may have content, but at some point the array is set to `[]` which updates the the markup accordingly.